# Java regular expression to detect timezone in SimpleDateFormat pattern

Tags: java, regex, timezone, pattern-matching, simpledateformat

Assume an application that parses thousands of date strings per second using some already known `SimpleDateFormat` patterns. The application needs to decide dynamically whether each such date pattern has a timezone, i.e. whether the date pattern string contains, anywhere in it and unquoted, the letters `Z` or `X`, in either upper case or lower case (i.e., 4 symbols in total).

Examples of such date patterns are:

- yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS Z  // Timezone (not quoted `Z` symbol)
- yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z' // No timezone (quoted `Z` symbol)
- EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss x yyyy // Timezone (not quoted `x` symbol)
- EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss'x'yyyy // No timezone (quoted `x` symbol)

One way of doing this is by using the `indexOf()` method of the `String` class, but this means running the method 4 times on each date pattern (or 2, if the date pattern string is converted to upper or lower case beforehand), plus checking whether the timezone symbol is quoted (in which case the pattern does not actually have a timezone).

The other choice is using a java regular expression, like

```
String date = ... // Get a SimpleDateFormat pattern

Pattern timezone = Pattern.compile("[^ZzXx]+[^'\"][ZzXx]{1}.*");

if (timezone.matcher(date).matches())
{
    // The date pattern does have a timezone
}
```

Is there a faster version for the above regular expression, i.e., for

- `"[^ZzXx]+[^'\"][ZzXx]{1}.*"`

or any other faster way, in general, for checking whether a `SimpleDateFormat` pattern does contain a timezone symbol?

Comment: Before asking "is there a faster way to do this" you must first ask "does my application even have performance problems in the first place?"

Comment: You can begin with making the Pattern a `static` attribute so it does not need to be compiled each time...

Comment: Since this seems like quite a low level optimization, you should probably analyze typical input data and provide stats on how frequent the scenario's are.

Comment: `SimpleDateFormat` is quite slow, so it would take some effort to find some way of examining a string for unquoted `X`/`Z` that is *so* bad as to be noticeably slow by comparison.

Comment: I am doing numerous optimizations (including SimpleDateformat and Pattern caching) that are irrelevant to the question. However, the regex does not seem optimal, so if it is the way to go, a faster version of it would be more than enough as an answer. :-)

Comment: From the first paragraph one could reasonably assume you're looking to examine the `SimpleDateFormat` _patterns_ themselves instead of the input dates, in which case you need to do this only once.  Please clarify the wording in the first paragraph if you mean to examine the input dates instead of the patterns.

Comment: Also, your regex approach will fail for input strings containing a quoted Z or X that is not the first character in the quoted string, as in `...'abZcd'...`, which will identify the Z as a timezone.

Comment: I added a few more words to further clarify the first paragraph. You are right about the regex, so any suggestions for improving speed and accuracy are very welcome!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest do it as simple as possible:

```
String string = "...";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\b(?<!')([xXzZ])(?!')\\b");
Matcher m = p.matcher(string);
if (m.find()) {
  String timeZone = m.group(1);
}
```

Comment: Hmmm... It does not work, as find() matches even the quoted timezone symbols, like 'Z'/

Comment: Yes, as per my examples in the question. My regex has backtracking, because the second character class is a subset of the first. Are you sure that your solution is faster?

Comment: @PNS - I believe so... Good luck!